# How can i get the classpath variables programmatically in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have several class path configured in eclipse in Preferences -> Java -> Build path -> Classpath variable. Is there an easy way to access to these variables from code?

Comment: What sort of code? Eclipse plug-ins can use various Eclipse JDT APIs to get this.

Comment: I'd like to use the most basic code possible, no extern library or plug-in, if possible

Comment: As far as I know, such variables can be used in the classpath/modulepath only. In the run configuration the resolved classpath/modulepath can be get by the variable `${project_classpath}`.